# Input and Output folders for Python

Tags: python, input, directory, output

I want to have the code pull from a input folder and export to a output folder. I would like to be able to read multiple files, run the code, and then output the multiple files into an output folder. How would I approach this?

'Here is my code:

```
import re

with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:

for line in fin:
    line = line.replace('set system host-name EX4300', 'hostname "EX4300"')
    line = line.replace('set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address', 'ip address')

    line = re.sub(r'set interfaces ge-0/0/0 description (.*)', r'interface 1/1\nname "\1"', line)
    line = re.sub(r'set interfaces ge-0/0/1 description (.*)', r'interface 1/2\nname "\1"', line)
```

#and so on...

fout.write(line)

Answer (score 0):

I would read the lines of the fin file and have a bunch of if statements to assess each line in fin. Then I would write the results to a new list. Once the new list is fully populated, write this new list to the output file.

A small example of this:

```
new_output_lines = []

with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        # create a new if/elif for every criteria
        if line == "set system host-name EX4300":
            new_output_lines.append('hostname "EX4300"')
        elif line.startswith("set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address"):
            new_output_lines.append('ip address')
        # add more criteria as needed
        else:
            new_output_lines.append(line)

with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
    for output_line in new_output_lines:
        fout.write(output_line)
```

The more complex your checks/replacements, the more "elif" statements are needed.